# How to Handle the RedirectMismatchException in Spring oAuth Server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2

When working with Spring OAuth Server there is a redirect_uri request parameter which when does not match any of the registered URIs in a oauth client details database table causes the oauth server to throw a RedirectMismatchException.

I cannot catch this RedirectMismatchException using the @ControllerAdvice. How can I catch the RedirectMismatchException in Spring oAuth Server?

I was thinking may be HttpSecurity can be configured with a filter that can be used to catch this exception but cannot figure which filter to use.

Please help me figure this out.